Getting request_before_redirect.url is None for POSTS requests in Locust Python
Trying to use locust following the documentation,
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/quickstart.html
from locust import HttpUser, task

class TestUser(HttpUser):

    # @task(1)
    # def health(self):
    #     self.client.get("/health")

    @task(2)
    def post_value(self):
        self.client.post(
                "/some/route", 
                headers={ 
                    "key1": "value1"
                },
                data={ 
                    "data1": "value1",
                })

GET requests are working fine. POST requests are throwing the below error in locust clients.py.
File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/email_bot/lib/python3.12/site-packages/locust/clients.py", line 286, in post
    return self.request("POST", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/email_bot/lib/python3.12/site-packages/locust/clients.py", line 196, in request
    url = request_before_redirect.url  # type: ignore
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'

Tried setting allow_redirects=True but still getting the same error. Not able to identify the root issue. Any pointers will be helpful.

is it possible that you got a connection error, like the server did not respond at all or you had the wrong address for it? Locust still shouldnt give you that error, but if that is the case, then it narrows it down. Are you on latest version of locust? (2.32.0)

The /health or in general GET requests are returning results. So the server connectivity seems fine. Yes, I'm using Locust 2.32.

What is your version of requests? (pip show requests) Maybe install without anaconda and see if there is any difference? Maybe your installation is corrupt somehow?

I checked it on my environment, in theory there are no errors. The code works
from locust import HttpUser, task

class TestUser(HttpUser):
    @task(2)
    def post_value(self):
        user = 'test'

        self.client.post(
            '/platform/j_spring_security_check',
            headers={
                'User-Agent': 'Test 66',
            },
            data={
                'j_username': user,
                'j_password': user,
                'j_rememberme': 'false'
            }
        )

Nginx log, where you can see that in response I received status code 200 and the User-Agent that I passed in the headers is taken into account
:11:52:06 +0000] "POST /platform/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Test 66"

